# component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the no. of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error:"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

When ***history.push("/")***  in demoPortalPage is called, sometimes it goes in infinite loop and set path infinite times.

***Screenshort of Errors:***
[screenshort of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYr3g.png)

**DemoPortalPage.jsx**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const authenticateDemoUser = async () => {
        const authData = {
            email: 'demo@gmail.com',
            password: '1234',
        };

        const checkUserAuth = await postRequest("authenticate", authData);

        if (checkUserAuth?.status >= 200 && checkUserAuth?.status < 300) {
            // sign in success action call
                await signInSuccess(checkUserAuth.data);
                await getAndSaveUserName();
                await setIsUserVerified(true);
                // localStorage.setItem('is_demo', "true")
                history.push("/");
            
        } else {
             await setIsUserVerified(false);
             history.push("/");
        }
    }
    authenticateDemoUser()

}, [])
```

**App.jsx**

```
 ....   
    <Route exact path={"/login"} render={() => (isUserVerified ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <LoginPage/>)} />
                               
    <Route exact path={"/demo-login"} component={DemoPortalPage} />
 ....
```

Please help me for solve this error

Comment: I think you should check return cancel = true statement for error, please make sure it is correct

Comment: I checked, because of return cancel = true statement is not throwing any error..  Error happens because path in app.jsx is repeatedly set when I continues refreshing route "/demo-login".

Comment: I think there is not enough info to help you. May you provide more details?

Comment: Added Screenshort of errors

Comment: Where is this isUserVerified flag, inside App.tsx or DemoPortalPage.jsx or both ?

Comment: isUserVerified state is store in redux store.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved and
I want to give you clarify for this thing on my case perspective..!
In my case it was happening because of asynchronous sequence..! Before it saves data in state, Page redirects to another page and next page don't get that data..! As per my routing code, If page don't have that specific data it checks again and again in loop and that's why infinite loop error occurs.

Thank you.